# Differential equation for an infinite series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to find the differential equation whose solution is the infinite series
$\displaystyle y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n!(n+1)!}(x/2)^{2n+1}$. I calculated $dy/dx=y'(x)$ and $d^2y/dx^2=y''(x)$ but could not combine them in the form $\alpha\; x^2\;y''(x)+\beta x\;y'(x)+\gamma y=0$. How can I do it? Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Also, how do you know its a second order ODE?

Comment: I don't believe this is true. Especially considering you have the symmetry $x \to -x$, $y \to -y$ invariant. Using the form you're hoping for $x \to -x$ gives the trivial symmetry $y \to y$.

Comment: Your $y(x)$ is a Bessel function of the first kind, so it satisfies Bessel's differential equation. These pop up in physics a lot.

Comment: $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are to be determined.